# Do we have an expression saying that a person is in a bad situation but doesn't dare to fight back but wait until the right moment?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Say, you are working for a bad boss who treats you badly. However, you don't dare to do anything to upset him but **sneakily** apply for a new job and wait until you get a new job offer.

When you get a new job offer, you can shout at him or sat bad words to him to ease your anger. You don't care if he sacks you or not because you ve got  a new job offer.

Another example, in a family, a person treats his/her spouse badly, but the spouse doesn't fight back but wait until the right moment to fight back.

**Do we have an expression saying that a person is in a bad situation but doesn't dare to fight back but wait until the right moment?**

For example, "**he bit the bullet and wait for the right moment to fight back**"

Comment: If someone is *advising* you "not to fight back but wait until the right moment", they might say ***Hold your horses**!* Sometimes *Hold your **water**!* - but at least *some* people think that one means ***Keep mum**!* in relation to a secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say:

> He wants to insult his boss, but he is **biding his time** until he gets a new job offer.

Or:

> She wanted to fight back against her spouse, but she was **biding her time** until the right moment arrived.

To ["bide one's time" means](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/bide-your-time) "to wait in a patient way for an opportunity to do something."